# Comparing memory addresses

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, memory-management

How would i compare two memory addresses from a fixed sized char array? Lets say i have two pointers, each pointing to a different memory location in the array:

```
char *ptr1; //points to a memory address in the array;
char *ptr2; //points to another memory address in the array;
```

If i do `printf("%p\n%p\n", ptr1, ptr2);` then it will print the memory addresses as hexadecimal.

```
output:
0x601240
0x601274
```

how would i store these into variables and are they comparable so that i can tell which memory address comes first in the array.

Another question:
Instead of %p if i do %d to print the memory address i get:

```
output:
6296128
6296180
```

are these valid memory addresses as well(i mean is this safe to use)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hexadecimal values are just representation of the address in the pointers. To compare two pointers(that point to elements of the same array or one past the end of the array), you can use code like

```
if (ptr1 < ptr2)
```

As for the format specifier, `%d` is not for pointers(though in some implementations, it prints the correct value, you shouldn't use it), use `%p` for `void *` pointers:

```
printf("%p\n%p\n", (void *)ptr1, (void *)ptr2);
```

Comment: what if I knew that the memory addresses stop at 0x700000 (for the sake of argument) and I wanted to check that the pointer isn't pointing outside the allowed range? Is `if (ptr1 > 0x700000) return -1;` valid?

Answer (score 3):

`0x601240` is the hex representation, and `6296128` the decimal representation, of exactly the same number. Similarly, `0x601274` is equal to `6296180`.  The `0x` is the indication that what follows is in hexadecimal format.

In your C/C++ code, the values of `ptr1` and `ptr2` can be compared with `<` or `>` to determine which one comes first in the array. (This can be done without worrying about the various ways they can be represented using `printf`.)

Comment: Although using `%d` happened to show the decimal value of the address in this instance, the behavior when `%d` is used to format a pointer is not defined by the C standard, and it is not generally safe to rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

those two outputs are the same, and has the same value. the first is in hexa, and the second is in decimal.

You may compare those two pointers, and any other pointers, and you may also do  some pointer arithmetic with them (subtract them etc.), if you wish.
However, if your program should be portable this can be very delicate. for example, check if the stack grows up or down, this may change the comparison you want to do...

Comment: As long as these pointers are in the same array, nothing will change this comparison.

Comment: Yes, I missed the part where he mentioned that it is pointer to objects on the same array. Nevertheless, I think it is important to mention this, as in the more general case, you do need to take this into consideration.